# How to get the text that was inputted by a user in a text box using Playwright for C#

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I am using Playwright in C#.  I have a text box:

```
<input id="NameFirst" name="NameFirst" type="text" >
```

In my Playwright test, I need to check to see if the name populating the text box is equal to the string "firstName".

This is what I have tried (along with practically every other Playwright assertion):
 `await Expect(RMSPage.Locator("#NameFirst")).ToContainTextAsync("firstName");`

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : Locator expected to contain text 'firstName'
But was: ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to get the **value** of the input. You need to use [ToHaveValueAsync](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value)

```
await Expect(RMSPage.Locator("#NameFirst")).ToHaveValueAsync("firstName");
```

Sometimes the values of an element is in placeholder / Value attribute and sometime as text.

So based on situation we can use

```
ToHaveAttributeAsync("type", "text");
ToContainTextAsync("substring")
ToHaveTextAsync(new Regex("Welcome, Test User"));
```